# M&B Warband: What if

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

So I deliberately made Swadia the strongest faction using savegame editor. All their lords are devoted to Harlaus and also each other. I brought back to Harlaus not only Swadian but also Vaegir and Sarranid lords from exile with 80 relationship points to him and all the others. My kingdom (Nords) occupy all our "originally" Nordic fiefs except Wercheg but it's getting quite challenging to keep them even with my skill of warfare (I can easily beat 100-120 Swadian or Vaegir knights if Sharpshooters or Marksmen won't help them. I have recently discovered that I can hold the Knuddar Castle with 20 Huscarls (I had about 300 but spawned only about 20 thanks to the Marnid's tactics very high skill, most of the time it was even less than that) and Great Long Axe againts 4000! I have never used it in order to ease gameplay!!! Not even single point of experience or skill or denar my character has has come from cheats.).

So my question is: If my kingdom will lose all the fiefs and lords but me will my kingdom be declared as defeated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your faction loses all feifs and castles, your faction will be defeated. This means that you will have to join another faction which can be hard if you were at war with all factions, or create your own faction and hope for the best.

Comment: You sure? Well my honor rating is when I checked last time it was eight hundred-something so joining other factions is quite easy (Harlaus is fond of me and Sanjar is friendly). I'm not a newbie. It's about 5000 days passed so I am at least very experienced I just didn't knew if that was the case.

Comment: @Davvy It doesn't matter the honour rating, as you will still be defeated. If you wish to have your own faction, the most important value is right-of-rule.

Comment: Well, I thought that honor rating would imply that I let the kings go after capturing them. RtR is 99 without help of companions. Mainly gained from peace declarations. Honestly I can wipe out everyone right now so surviving or even safety is not any of my concern. I just want to be the weaker kingdom vassal but still beating the stronger one.